# не могу понять в чём ошибка Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    // Cache selectors
   var lastId,
       topMenu = $("#article-nav"),
       topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
       // All list items
       menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
       // Anchors corresponding to menu items
       scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
          var item = $($(this).attr("#"));
          if (item.length) { return item; }
       });
 
// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
   menuItems.click(function(e){
      var href = $(this).attr("#"),
         offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
         scrollTop: offsetTop
      }, 300);
      e.preventDefault();
   });
 
// Bind to scroll
   $(window).scroll(function(){
      // Get container scroll position
      var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
 
      // Get id of current scroll item
      var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
         if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
            return this;
      });
      // Get the id of the current element
      cur = cur[cur.length-1];
      var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
 
      if (lastId !== id) {
         lastId = id;
         // Set/remove active class
         menuItems
             .parent().removeClass("active")
             .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
      }
   });
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined, но этот элемент существует, в чём может быть ошибка ?

Answer (score 1):

ну думаю ошибка в том что `$(this).offset() - undefined` а в документации есть следующее

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden
> elements or accounting for margins set on the  document element.
>
> While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with
> visibility:hidden set, display:none is excluded from the rendering
> tree and thus has a position that is undefined.

смысл: jQuery не поддерживает получение координат у скрытых объектов